# Restart Python Script after BadStatusLine Error

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, streaming

I have a program here that streams market prices and executes orders based on the prices, however, every once in a while (few hours or so) it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Users/mattduhon/trading4.py", line 30, in trade
    execution.execute_order(event)
  File "/Users/mattduhon/execution.py", line 34, in execute_order
    response = self.conn.getresponse().read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1073, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 415, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 379, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
BadStatusLine: ''
```

once this error occurs the program keeps running without executing orders, it simply streams rates.  My question is how can I ensure the program will keep trading?  Either by restarting the program or ignoring the error or something else?  Thanks in advance.

additional code:

excecution.py

```
import httplib
import urllib


class Execution(object):
    def __init__(self, domain, access_token, account_id):
        self.domain = domain
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.account_id = account_id
        self.conn = self.obtain_connection()

    def obtain_connection(self):
        return httplib.HTTPSConnection(self.domain)

    def execute_order(self, event):
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.access_token
        }
        params = urllib.urlencode({
            "instrument" : event.instrument,
            "units" : event.units,
            "type" : event.order_type,
            "side" : event.side,
            "stopLoss" : event.stopLoss,
            "takeProfit" : event.takeProfit

        })
        self.conn.request(
            "POST",
            "/v1/accounts/%s/orders" % str(self.account_id),
            params, headers
        )
        response = self.conn.getresponse().read()  #Line34////////////
        print response
```

And the Trading4.py

```
import Queue
import threading
import time
import json


from execution import Execution
from settings4 import STREAM_DOMAIN, API_DOMAIN, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_ID
from strategy4 import TestRandomStrategy
from streaming import StreamingForexPrices



#Checks for events and executes order                
def trade(events, strategy, execution):

    while True:

        try:
            event = events.get(False)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass

        else:
            if event is not None:
                if event.type == 'TICK':
                    strategy.calculate_signals(event)
                elif event.type == 'ORDER':
                    print 
                    execution.execute_order(event)  #Line30//////////////


if __name__ == "__main__":
    heartbeat = 0  # Half a second between polling
    events = Queue.Queue()

# Trade 1 unit of EUR/USD
    instrument = "EUR_USD"
    units = 10

    prices = StreamingForexPrices(
        STREAM_DOMAIN, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_ID,
        instrument, events
    )
    execution = Execution(API_DOMAIN, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_ID)

    strategy = TestRandomStrategy(instrument, units, events)


#Threads
    trade_thread = threading.Thread(target=trade, args=(events, strategy, execution))
    price_thread = threading.Thread(target=prices.stream_to_queue, args=[])
    # stop_thread = threading.Thread(target=rates, args=(events,))      

# Start both threads
    trade_thread.start()
    price_thread.start()
    # stop_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

catch the exception:

```
        from httplib import BadStatusLine

       ............

        try:
            response = self.conn.getresponse().read()  #Line34////////////
        except BadStatusLine as e:
            print(e)
        else:          
            print response
```

Comment: I tried something similar and couldn't get it, let me give your a go.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries, If you actually want to restart the script that can be done in the except block.

Comment: So far so good!  I think your method should do the trick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2883183, good, glad it helped. If you get any other httplib related errors you can add them to the except block